# Normal body text within tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I want the paragraphs in the `tcolorbox` to be formatted like body text. (I'm using `tcolorboxes` as subsections.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that LaTeX clears the paragraph indentation in a `minipage` or `\parbox`. But it's possible to tell `tcolorbox` to reapply it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\tcbset{before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Store the current value of `parindent` and apply it in the tcolorbox.

[image: randyrandersonTcolorboxParagraphs]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlength{\saveparindent}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\saveparindent}{\parindent}
    \lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \setlength{\parindent}{\saveparindent}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

---

To do this globally, you can missuse the setting for the font. But i rather suggest to make a feature request to the author.

```
\tcbset{fontupper={\setlength{\parindent}{\saveparindent}}}
```

Comment: How can you apply it simultaneously to all `tcolorboxes` in the document, i.e., using `tcbset`?

Comment: @RandyRanderson Please see the update.

Comment: `before upper` seems to be the better hook to change.